# create callback API

Tags: javascript, php, api, callback

New Restful API's like Google, OpenStreetview use a simple call back mechanism.
Basically you call the API, adding a parameter `&callback=my function`. 
When executing a call to this API, as a result my function is called passing a JSON dataset.

I am trying to create the same mechanisme for a API I am building for my personal use.

As far as I understood my API needs to return a javascript, that calls the function that is passed in a script.
For a test I created this:

```
    function apiCall(URL,values, keyPair,cBackPair) {
    // URL specifics URL to call
    // keyPair: <keyname>=<key>; leave black if unneeded
    // cBacPair: <callBackParametername>=<functionname>
    // called is: URL?values&keypair&cBackPair

    var request = (keyPair)?'&'+keyPair:'';
    request = URL + '?'+ encodeURI(values) + request + '&' + cBackPair;     
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src", request);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
 }

function callAPI() {
    apiCall('http://xllent.nl/map/ajax/answer.php','q=one','','s=doit');
}

function doit(result) {
    alert(result);
}
```

To test I call `callAPI` onload.

The script `answer.php` is very basic:

```
<?$s = $_GET['s'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
doit('jeroen');
</script>
```

Later the script would use `$s` to call the right script, and of course supply user data.

For now I am just trying to get the script `doit('jeroen');` to be run. But nothing happens.
Typing `javascript:doit('jeroen');` in the browser window gives the result I would expect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: restful api's use a web client such as curl to open the callback url, it has nothing to do with javascript

Answer (score 2):

Don't surround your javascript with `<script>` tags. You are not generating a HTML file with a javascript body.. You should think of this as if you're generating a javascript file on fly.

Javascript files also don't start and end with `<script>`